# SEO Is it Good or Bad to add Company Name to Title Attribute?

Tags: seo, search-engines, links, alternative, title-attribute

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the title attribute (not tag) important to SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/is-the-title-attribute-not-tag-important-to-seo)

So while I'm filling out title / alt attributes I noticed I was just automatically adding my company name to almost every links title tag (ex. title="Company Name Video Services", etc.) but is this a good thing or bad thing? Will the repetition kill benefit of the keyword? Should I fill it with better keywords since my company name should theoretically be everywhere in the content anyway?

Comment: related to the title attribute: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/is-the-title-attribute-not-tag-important-to-seo