# Does adding a description to menu links have any SEO value?

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the title attribute (not tag) important to SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/is-the-title-attribute-not-tag-important-to-seo)

I am a bit lazy and I rarely enter anything in the "Description" field (which is a title attribute) when adding menu links. Does the presence of a description aid or hinder SEO?